# Get GUID of specific drive

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I would like to find out the Drive-GUID for a specific drive letter.
I have following code:

```
Function GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(lpszVolumeMountPoint: LPCTSTR; lpszVolumeName: LPTSTR; cchBufferLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'kernel32.dll' name 'GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Buffer: array[0..50] of AnsiChar;
begin
  if GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint('C:\', Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer)) then
  begin
    showmessage(buffer); // Expected: "\\?\Volume{deadbeef-895e-4a1d-9d64-9b82fa068d76}\"
  end
  else RaiseLastOSError; // Actual: ERROR_INVALID_NAME (123).
end;
```

I am getting the error `ERROR_INVALID_NAME (123)`, but I do not know why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling the Unicode version of the function but passing ANSI text. Thus the first argument you pass is wrongly encoded and hence the error message.

This program demonstrates how it should be done:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

function GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointA(lpszVolumeMountPoint: PAnsiChar;
  lpszVolumeName: PAnsiChar; cchBufferLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'kernel32.dll';

procedure Main;
var
  Buffer: array [0 .. 49] of AnsiChar;
begin
  Win32Check(GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointA('C:\', Buffer, Length(Buffer)));
  Writeln(Buffer);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Since it is clear that you are using a pre-Unicode version of Delphi (otherwise your program would not compile), I have given you ANSI code above. If you ever upgrade to a Unicode version of Delphi then you'd write it like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

function GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW(lpszVolumeMountPoint: PWideChar;
  lpszVolumeName: PWideChar; cchBufferLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'kernel32.dll';

procedure Main;
var
  Buffer: array [0 .. 49] of WideChar;
begin
  Win32Check(GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW('C:\', Buffer, Length(Buffer)));
  Writeln(Buffer);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Or if you want code that works in all versions of Delphi, you can do this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

const
  Win32ImportSuffix = {$IFDEF Unicode}'W'{$ELSE}'A'{$ENDIF};

function GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointA(lpszVolumeMountPoint: PAnsiChar;
  lpszVolumeName: PAnsiChar; cchBufferLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'kernel32.dll';
function GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW(lpszVolumeMountPoint: PWideChar;
  lpszVolumeName: PWideChar; cchBufferLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'kernel32.dll';
function GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(lpszVolumeMountPoint: PChar;
  lpszVolumeName: PChar; cchBufferLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'kernel32.dll' name 'GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint' + Win32ImportSuffix;

procedure Main;
var
  Buffer: array [0 .. 49] of Char;
begin
  Win32Check(GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint('C:\', Buffer, Length(Buffer)));
  Writeln(Buffer);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```